# Parse 1st Google Result android code

Tags: android, parsing, search

I would like somebody to give me an example code to parse only the first google result.
For example i open http://google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&btnI=1&q=microsoft.
This url goes direct to url of microsoft.com.

How can i parse the exact url and save it to a string?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Start by writing some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i don't know how to do it.....if i tried i will have already shared it  here...could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSON/Atom Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html).

In short, send an HTTP request ([HTTP GET in Android](http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/)) with a query in REST format and you will get an HTTP response with search result in JSON format. Just parse the result ([JSON parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)) and voilà!

All you need is basically in Google Search documentation, so read it first. Pay special attention to:

- [the URI format for a search](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html#WorkingResults)
- [Query parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html#api_params) - you may need "num" parameter, as it specifies number of search results

Now you can start writing some code and come back if you have problems.