# Open first Link searched against a keyword

Tags: android, url, webview, android-webview

I have 2 activities in my app, First Activity is simple editText and submit Button, When I press submit, it launches webView Activity and searches the keyword entered in the first activity. Now I want to open the first link Automatically in webview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   WebView webView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
       webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
       String query = "firebase";// Get the text from EditText here
       String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+query;
       webView.loadUrl(url);
   }
}
```

Comment: which first link you want to load.? Please provide more details of your query.

Comment: first link that shows up against a keyword , Like if you search firebase , it should open first link on search results

Comment: Got it? @DHAVALASODARIYA

Comment: Yes, you can not do it with webview. You need to parse answer of final URL and detect the first link and then load it in webview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse 1st Google Result android code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733074/parse-1st-google-result-android-code)

Comment: "answer of final URL" what does that mean

Comment: Answer of final URL means the detailed response of URL you have prepared. i.e. in your code : response of this URL `String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+query;`